# Kendo UI Grid Data with List<T> (evolve to DataTable)

Tags: list, datagrid, kendo-ui

I'm using Kendo UI and I have some trouble ...

I want to use a Grid to display data.

I've got a List with a DLL, my DLL works, I can have all informations , I've tested it.
How can I do to use data from the list (each log has a type (Message-Error ...) , an at (02/05/2013 15:00) and a Message("Hi I"m a message")) ?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Please provide a code snippet and some context to this. You mention a DLL, but that doesn't seem to make any sense in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using a DataTable inspite of a List. Furthermore, I delete my log class, cause she's finally useless

I load my DataTable in my Controller, and can easily display it !

If someone needs information don't hesitate

Answer (score 0):

This is my class to parse my XML.

```
public class Read
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Cette fonction va lire un fichier XML
    /// et renvoyer une liste de log
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path">Chemin du fichier</param>
    /// <returns>On retourne la liste de logs</returns>
    public static List<Log> loadXML(string path)
    {
        // On crée une nouvelle instance d'une liste de log
        List<Log> liste = new List<Log>();

        /* On créer un using pour rendre la fermeture de notre flux implicite
         * à l'intérieur duquel on déclare un reader qui réalisera notre traitement
         * tant qu'il y aura quelque chose à lire
         */
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);

        var logResults = (from log in doc.Descendants("log")
                          select log).ToList();

        foreach (XElement addLog in logResults)
        {
            string dateCreation = addLog.Attribute("at").Value;
            TYPE typeLog = affectationType(addLog.Attribute("type").Value);
            string message = addLog.Value;
            string stack = null;

            if(addLog.Element("stack")!=null)
                stack = addLog.Element("stack").Value;

            liste.Add(new Log(DateTime.Parse(dateCreation),typeLog,message,stack));
        }

        // Et on retourne finalement la liste
        return liste;
    }
```

And each log is like

```
public class Log
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Permet de savoir à quelle heure le log a été créé
    /// </summary>
    internal DateTime at;

    /// <summary>
    /// Permet de connaître le type du log
    /// Cette variable est du type enum <c>TYPE</c>
    /// </summary>
    internal TYPE type;

    /// <summary>
    /// Message de base que possède n'importe quel log
    /// </summary>
    internal string exceptionMessage;

    /// <summary>
    /// S'il s'agit d'une exception, il y aura un stack d'exception
    /// </summary>
    internal string stackException;

    /// <summary>
    /// Message de l'InnerException liée
    /// </summary>
    internal string innerMessage;

    /// <summary>
    /// Stack de l'InnerException
    /// </summary>
    internal string stackInner;
```

My XML is like

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<logs>
  <log at="05/02/2013 15:07:00" type="Message">Test</log>
  <log at="05/02/2013 15:07:00" type="Exception">It's an exception <stack> an its stack</stack></log>
</logs>
```

I'd like to display something like

```
     AT                 TYPE          MESSAGE          STACK
05/02/2013 15:07:00    MESSAGE          Test              /
05/02/2013 15:07:00    EXCEPTION       It's an ...      And its stack
```